# Javascript - having trouble with changeClass() onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make movable images within a container. I'm using the jQuery plugin from here: http://threedubmedia.com/. I'd like things to appear within the container when I click on them but I'm having trouble changing the class of my object (.item) outside of my container. Thanks in advance! Sorry if I've made stupid mistakes, I am just learning javascript.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js" ></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.event.drag.live-2.2.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
   var $div = $('#container');
   $('.drag')
      .drag("start",function( ev, dd ){
         dd.limit = $div.offset();
         dd.limit.bottom = dd.limit.top + $div.outerHeight() - $( this ).outerHeight();
         dd.limit.right = dd.limit.left + $div.outerWidth() - $( this ).outerWidth();
      })
      .drag(function( ev, dd ){
         $( this ).css({
            top: Math.min( dd.limit.bottom, Math.max( dd.limit.top, dd.offsetY ) ),
            left: Math.min( dd.limit.right, Math.max( dd.limit.left, dd.offsetX ) )
         });   
      });
});
</script>

<div id="container"></div>
<div class="drag" style="left:40px;"></div>
<div class="drag" style="left:120px;"></div>
<div class="drag" style="left:200px;"></div>
<div class="item"></div>

<style type="text/css">
.drag {
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid #89B;
   background: #BCE;
   height: 58px;
   width: 58px;
   cursor: move;
   top: 120px;
   }
#container {
   height: 299px;
   border: 1px dashed #888;
   }

.item {
   height: 58px;
   width: 58px;
   background: #000;
}

</style>​



<script type="text/javascript">  
function changeclass() {
$('.item').click(function(){ 
   $(this).removeClass('item');
   $(this).addClass('drag'); 
});
}

</script>
```

Comment: error, issue problem u r facing is?

Comment: If you have made any fiddle can you share ?

Answer (score 0):

Probable reason could be, ready block for `changeClass()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function changeclass() {
    $('.item').click(function(){ 
       $(this).removeClass('item');
       $(this).addClass('drag'); 
    });
    }
});
```

if you need to just change element class on click event then try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.item').click(function(){ 
       $(this).removeClass('item');
       $(this).addClass('drag'); 
    });         
});
```

Comment: Thank you Zaheer,

I incorporated your code and it allows me to change class, however, I can't move the objects that subsume the new class name after I click on them. They take on the css class but not the js at the top of the code. Any ideas? Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

When your below script is rendered | Check this fiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tABed/)

`var $div = $('#container');` your document is not ready that time.

Call your script on window.onload or $(document).ready

Example

```
    window.onload = function(){

    jQuery(function($){
       var $div = $('#container');
       $('.drag')
          .drag("start",function( ev, dd ){
             dd.limit = $div.offset();
             dd.limit.bottom = dd.limit.top + $div.outerHeight() - $( this ).outerHeight();
             dd.limit.right = dd.limit.left + $div.outerWidth() - $( this ).outerWidth();
          })
          .drag(function( ev, dd ){
             $( this ).css({
                top: Math.min( dd.limit.bottom, Math.max( dd.limit.top, dd.offsetY ) ),
                left: Math.min( dd.limit.right, Math.max( dd.limit.left, dd.offsetX ) )
             });   
          });
    });


    $('.item').each(function(){ 
    $(this).click(function(){ 
    $(this).removeClass('item');
    $(this).addClass('drag'); 
    });
    }); 
}
```